# StackOverflow Exception when setting object variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, stack-overflow

I am trying to extract data from a sql table, write it to an object and in turn put that in a list.
I'm using VS2017, C# and MS-SQL 2008.

When I run the code it extracts the data from the SQL table; dumps it into some variables (I know this isn't the fastest, I just wanted to confirm I was getting them), I instantiate the object and try to set the first value, I then get the stack overflow on the set operation.

Why is it fine setting a variable and printing to screen, but not putting it into a variable?

Error;

> System.StackOverflowException   HResult=0x800703E9   Message=Exception
>   of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Class;

```
class Company
{
    public String MDWRowNumber { get => MDWRowNumber; set => MDWRowNumber = value; } //errors here on set => MDWRowNumber = value
    public String MDWIdNumber { get => MDWIdNumber; set => MDWIdNumber = value; }
    public String MDWCompanyName { get => MDWCompanyName; set => MDWCompanyName = value; }
}
```

Main;

```
sql = "SELECT RowNo, Id, Name FROM Company;";
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(2).ToString());

    a = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    b = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    c = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(a + " | " + b + " | " + c); // writes correct values as expected

    Company company = new Company();
    company.MDWRowNumber = a; /////Errors here/////
    company.MDWIdNumber = b;
    company.MDWCompanyName = c;
    //Company company = new Company()
    //    {
    //        MDWRowNumber = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), ///// without all junk above errors here /////
    //        MDWIdNumber = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
    //        MDWCompanyName = reader.GetValue(2).ToString()
    //    };

    CompanyList.Add(company);
}

Console.WriteLine(CompanyList.First().MDWCompanyName);

reader.Close();
command.Dispose();
```

Comment: All your getters and setters call themselves recursively, just use `public string MDWRowNumber { get; set; }`

Comment: @Lee Thanks for that, it's been driving me nuts for hours. Please write this as answer and i'll accept and upvote

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
public String MDWRowNumber { get => MDWRowNumber;
```

The property calls itself - hence the stack overflow.

Either use a private variable,

```
private string _MDWRowNumber;
public String MDWRowNumber { get => _MDWRowNumber; set => _MDWRowNumber = value; }
```

or an auto property

```
public String MDWRowNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your class you have

`public String MDWRowNumber { get => MDWRowNumber; set => MDWRowNumber = value; }`

you dont need all that, it should just be

`public String MDWRowNumber { get; set; }`

by putting itself in the underlying variable you've confused it.